# Jerkyll - Command not found

Tags: jekyll

I read through the entire tutorial here - http://jekyllbootstrap.com/lessons/jekyll-introduction.html

and after I had installed the engine and a theme, I expected the following to launch my site locally:

```
jerkyll --server
```

But

```
command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some google searches (number of mindless accepting of google's spelling correction) before I realized it's jekyll not jerkyll! jekyll command is readily found by my mac :)

Comment: "Jerkyll" is what you call it when it isn't working.